# Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I saw a lot of questions similar to mine and I tried to find the answer but I didnt find it. Please someone help me.
My app works locally but not in heroku

This is what I got when I try heroku run rake db:migrate

```
    rake aborted!
LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:406:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:975:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:465:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:406:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:975:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:465:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

in my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

In my gemfile

```
group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'
end
ruby '2.4.6'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
```

When I push the updates to heroku I got this

```
Enumerating objects: 54, done.
Counting objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 3.53 KiB | 1.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.0.2
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.6
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Using rake 13.0.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
remote:        Using minitest 5.14.0
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.4
remote:        Using erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.6
remote:        Using rack 2.2.2
remote:        Using nio4r 2.5.2
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.4
remote:        Using msgpack 1.3.3
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.12.2
remote:        Using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Using thor 1.0.1
remote:        Using pg 1.2.3
remote:        Using puma 3.12.4
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Fetching sqlite3 1.3.13
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.8.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.6
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.9
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.4.6
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
remote:        Fetching sassc 2.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.2.0
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using loofah 2.4.0
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Using sass 3.7.4
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.4
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using railties 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using rails 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.1.0
remote:        Installing sassc 2.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Installing font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20200328-229-1062pnh.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:         --with-opt-dir
remote:         --without-opt-dir
remote:         --with-opt-include
remote:         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:         --with-opt-lib
remote:         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:         --with-make-prog
remote:         --without-make-prog
remote:         --srcdir=.
remote:         --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:         --with-sqlite3-config
remote:         --without-sqlite3-config
remote:         --with-pkg-config
remote:         --without-pkg-config
remote:         --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --with-sqlite3-include
remote:         --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:         --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:         --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13' --source
remote:        'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          sqlite3
remote:        Bundler Output: Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Using rake 13.0.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
remote:        Using minitest 5.14.0
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.4
remote:        Using erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.6
remote:        Using rack 2.2.2
remote:        Using nio4r 2.5.2
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.4
remote:        Using msgpack 1.3.3
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.12.2
remote:        Using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Using thor 1.0.1
remote:        Using pg 1.2.3
remote:        Using puma 3.12.4
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Fetching sqlite3 1.3.13
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.8.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.6
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.9
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.4.6
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
remote:        Fetching sassc 2.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.2.0
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using loofah 2.4.0
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Using sass 3.7.4
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.4
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using railties 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using rails 5.2.4.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.1.0
remote:        Installing sassc 2.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Installing font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20200328-229-1062pnh.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:         --with-opt-dir
remote:         --without-opt-dir
remote:         --with-opt-include
remote:         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:         --with-opt-lib
remote:         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:         --with-make-prog
remote:         --without-make-prog
remote:         --srcdir=.
remote:         --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:         --with-sqlite3-config
remote:         --without-sqlite3-config
remote:         --with-pkg-config
remote:         --without-pkg-config
remote:         --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --with-sqlite3-include
remote:         --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:         --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:         --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_60ff83ec452079f22bf4bbc72a038f83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13' --source
remote:        'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          sqlite3
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to limoexotic.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/limoexotic.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/limoexotic.git'
```

Comment: I suggest reading [this article on heroku.com](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3). Most important quote: _"While easy to use, SQLite is not intended as a production grade database. Instead Heroku provides production grade PostgreSQL databases as a service."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. when I deploy in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901798/error-loading-the-sqlite3-active-record-adapter-when-i-deploy-in-heroku)

Comment: @Chris Thank you :) Yes it did I replace gem sqlite with gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'

Answer (score -1):

You should to change your Gemfile to this:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'
ruby '2.4.6'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
```

Because now your sqlite3 gem is fetched only for `development` environment. When you deploy your application to heroku, it runs your application in `production` environment

Comment: I got this error An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13' --source
remote:        'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: try to remove version from your Gemfile. `gem 'sqlite3'` instead of `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'`

Comment: But SQLite doesn't work on Heroku due to its ephemeral filesystem. A much _better_ solution would be to use a client-server database like PostgreSQL in both development and production. See the article that @spickermann referenced in a comment on the question above.

Comment: It didnt work. I updated my answer after I replace sqlite3 instead of postgres in the database.yml file