# Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I am working on a simple rails webapp and it has been working just fine when I tried to run

```
rails console
```

and got this error:

```
2020-08-03 17:30:51 -0600: Rack app error handling request { GET /microposts }
#<LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.>
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:346:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:327:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `run'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:28:in `before'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `catch'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `block in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block in halting'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:111:in `run!'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:73:in `block in run!'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:76:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Im running ruby 2.7.0 and rails 6.0.3.2, now if I try to run:

```
rails server
```

I get the same error. I've tried commenting out the spring gem as well as running spring stop to no avail. Am I missing something obvious? It seems strange to me that the only thing that changed between it working and not working was trying to run `rails console`.

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'

# Use Puma as the app servergit
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  # # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '3.2.1'
  gem 'spring', '2.1.0'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '1.2.3'
end
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Im ruuning this inside of rubymine on windows 10 if that makes any difference.

UPDATE:

I have tried completely removing sqlite from my gem file but am still receiving the same error. I then checked my Gemfile.lock file for dependencies and could find none. Why am I getting this error?

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
    activerecord (6.0.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
    activestorage (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.7)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.33.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    ffi (1.13.1-x64-mingw32)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.8.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    listen (3.2.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.6.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.1)
    msgpack (1.3.3-x64-mingw32)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.10-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (1.2.3-x64-mingw32)
    public_suffix (4.0.5)
    puma (4.3.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.3.2)
      actioncable (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      actiontext (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.3.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.7.1)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0-x64-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.7)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2020.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    web-console (4.0.4)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.4.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.0)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.2)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (= 3.2.1)
  pg (= 1.2.3)
  puma (~> 4.1)
  rails (~> 6.0.3, >= 6.0.3.2)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring (= 2.1.0)
  spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.1)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 4.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.1p83

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle install` before running your rails server ?

Comment: Btw, is this answer helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901798/error-loading-the-sqlite3-active-record-adapter-when-i-deploy-in-heroku

Comment: I also tried that, unfortunately no luck.

Comment: What is your RAILS_ENV?

Comment: Please downgrade sqlite3 version to 1.3.6 on your Gemfile. 
Read https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35153.

Comment: Ill give that a try. Right now it is defined as follows with the same problem:                   
 ` gem 'sqlite3', '>= 1.3.6','<1.5' `

Comment: @Nek I tried running it on 1.3.6 with no luck. Also the documentation with rails 60.+ states that you must run at minimum sqlite 1.4. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/6_0_release_notes.html   in section 8.3

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate the error but I noticed your gemfile indicates ruby 2.7.1 and the error messaging is looking in 2.7.0

Comment: I didn't even notice that! I'll check into it.

Comment: I am actually running off of a 2.7.0 SDK, but for some reason the project got setup on 2.7.1. Do you possibly know why this would have happened or if there is a way to backtrack to 2.7.0?